# -bash: kafka-server-start.sh: command not found

Tags: apache-kafka

After I installed kafka through homebrew, and my current version is 0.9.0.1.

I was following the steps in [this post](https://dtflaneur.wordpress.com/2015/10/05/installing-kafka-on-mac-osx/). At step 3, when I run following command in terminal

```
kafka-server-start.sh /usr/local/etc/kafka/server.properties
```

I got: `-bash: kafka-server-start.sh: command not found`

And I tried to solve this and search for solution for this online and anywhere. But I could not find any.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 19):

You probably need to put a `./` in front of your command. Like this:

```
./kafka-server-start.sh /usr/local/etc/kafka/server.properties
```

This of course you are currently in the `$KAFKA_HOME/bin` directory. Alternatively, you could try:

```
export KAFKA_HOME=/path/to/kafka/install/directory
$KAFKA_HOME/bin/kafka-server-start.sh /usr/local/etc/kafka/server.properties
```

Or you could do:

```
export PATH=$KAFKA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

And then run your original command without the `./`

Comment: I still get "command not found" even though I added $KAFKA_HOME/bin to path, anyone else have the same issue?

Answer (score 7):

I faced the same problem on mac but below command worked well

```
kafka-topics  --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic myTopic
```

Answer (score 2):

Please Follow the below steps and it should work as I faced the exact issue

to find the JAVA exact path below is the command

```
ls -l /etc/alternatives/java

lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 31 Jun  8 01:15 /etc/alternatives/java -> /opt/java/jdk1.8.0_202/bin/java
```

Set the java home

```
export JAVA_HOME=/opt/java/jdk1.8.0_202/bin/java
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/java/jdk1.8.0_202/bin/java
```

set the Kafka path as below

```
nano .bashrc
export PATH=/home/biraj/kafka_2.12-2.2.1/bin:$PATH
```

Now the kafka-server-start.sh should work

Answer (score 1):

Go to kafka_2.12-2.3.1/bin folder.

```
cd kafka_2.12-2.3.1/bin
```

Then enter this command.

```
export PATH=$KAFKA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Thats it! 
Now Execute
 `kafka-server-start.`

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `.sh` extension and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

As per the link mentioned
In step 3 
don't go to the address mentioned i.e :

```
/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/0.9.0.1/bin/
```

Instead, go to the following path :

```
/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/0.9.0.1/libexec/bin/
```

and enter the command with `./` added if path is not set.

```
kafka-server-start.sh /usr/local/etc/kafka/server.properties
```

OR

```
./kafka-server-start.sh /usr/local/etc/kafka/server.properties
```

I Tested this on version `0.11.0.1`. Just check your version. Also you should have `kafka-server-start.sh` file in the mentioned path.

Then you can execute that command. just try with or without `./`

Answer (score 0):

Add kafka folder to your C:\ drive where java is also installed. It worked for me

Answer (score -3):

Are you in the right folder? I had the same issue when I was in the bin folder without realising it. you have to be at the root folder of kafka.

See: https://www.sohamkamani.com/blog/2017/11/22/how-to-install-and-run-kafka/